# opscenter REST API when authentication is enabled

Tags: opscenter

I enabled authentication on my opscenter node as per [this](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscEnablingAuth.html) . I've a python script that periodically invokes opscenter actions through the Opscenter REST APIs. From the REST API documentation, it looked like all I had to do was invoke these methods with basic HTTP auth (see [this](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/api/docs/authentication.html#authentication)). But these calls always failed with a "user must be logged in" error.

After poking around the javascript that runs when I use the opscenter's web frontend, I figured that I must actually invoke the login method to create a session and use that session to invoke other methods, such as:

```
session = requests.Session()
login_body = '{"username": "%s", "password": "%s"}' % (opsc_uname, opsc_pwd)
login_resp = session.post("http://{url}/login".format(url=opsc_url), data=login_body).json()
clusterconf = session.get("http://{url}/cluster-configs".format(url=opsc_url)).json()
```

Is the api documentation (that claims to use basic http auth) wrong? Or am I doing something incorrectly? The opscenter version I'm using is 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You figured it out correctly, OpsCenter 5.1 uses sessions instead of basic auth. You've been looking at 5.0 docs, that's why it wasn't documented. Here's a correct [link](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/api/docs/authentication.html#authentication).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the documentation link the user "arre" has posted above when you implement that method ensure you dont include the { } curly braces, so for example use

```
curl -H 'opscenter-session: d6c5e198b9b5ffeab9fd8dea6fb012aa' http://127.0.0.1:8888/permissions/user
```

Instead of

```
curl -H 'opscenter-session: {d6c5e198b9b5ffeab9fd8dea6fb012aa}' http://127.0.0.1:8888/permissions/user
```